# Best way to handle multiple parameters in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Suppose we have an app that does a hotel search and requires multiple GET parameters to run, ie LocationName, NumberOfGuests, StartRating, PaymentOption, MealPlanOption and so on.

Whats the best way to handle this in an Angular2 Router to be able to copy-paste the url in the browser?

Comment: What do you need GET parameters for? How should the URL look like? Is the parameter list static or may only some or none be provided instead of all?

Comment: A third party form send circa 20 values that are necessary to run the angular2 app. The app was a standard server-side app before and the url looked like this: http://mesearchappdomain.com/locationsearch ?LocationName=NewYork&StarRating=5&MealPlan=RoomOnly&NumberofGuests=2...

Comment: The router doesn't care about query parameters, only route parameters (part of the path). You can pass them. You need to take care that they are forwarded, otherwise they are dropped on redirect or routerLink click.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I forward them?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html `preserveQueryParams` can be passed to `routerLink` or `router.navigate()`